# Sentence starting with a verb without question or conditional

Tags: verb, word-order, grammar-identification

> "Dennoch ist es tiefgründiger, als man zunächst meinen könnte. Erscheinen doch beide Faktoren zunächst als Antagonisten: Ist die Unsicherheit groß, so ist das Vertrauen gering."

The sentence beginning with the verb "erscheinen" clearly isn't a question nor is a conditional so why does it open with a verb?

Comment: Side note: Besides question and conditional, in imperative the verb is also at the beginning: *Iss endlich auf!*

Comment: Klingt für mich wie ein Nebensatz. Ich hätte vor 'erscheinen' nur ein Komma gesetzt. Ist das ein Zitat? Von wem?

Comment: @userunknown Hat nichts damit zu tun. Es ist gar nicht so untypisch, zumal das direkt 2x in dem Beispiel vorkommt. Auffälligkeit: Es folgt ein ", so ist". *Setzt man das Verb an den Anfang, so ist ... * (Folgerung) oder *Hat die Mannschaft auch hart gekämpft, so ist die Mühe umsonst gewesen* (Gegenteiliges).

Comment: @Em1: Ja, im zweiten Satz sehe ich auch einen kompletten Satz. Ist es auch wieder ein Satz mit Verb in der Poleposition, so war mir das gar nicht aufgefallen.

Comment: I agree with @userunknown. If I read the sentence aloud, it sounds perfectly find. When I read the sentences the full stop looks very odd. Maybe it is possible to do this, but then I don't like it.

Comment: @0x6d64: Indeed. It's similar to "Ich mache jetzt Schluss. Weil ich losmuss."

Comment: @Em1: Was hat nichts womit zu tun? "Setzt man das Verb an den Anfang" ist genauso ein Nebensatz wie "Hat die Mannschaft auch hart gekämpft". Beginnt man Sätze mit einem Nebensatz, so muss ein Hauptsatz folgen. `:-)`

Comment: @HendrikVogt Stimmt. ^^

Answer (score 12):

As user unknown said in his comment, "Erscheinen doch beide ..." is a *subordinate* clause, so the grammatically correct version would read

> Dennoch ist es tiefgründiger, als man zunächst meinen könnte, erscheinen doch beide Faktoren zunächst als Antagonisten: ...

To be precise, this subordinate clause is a beast called "uneingeleiteter Nebensatz", i.e., there's no conjunction such as *obwohl* introducing the clause. Here, the clause begins with a verb! Note that one could also write

> Dennoch ist es tiefgründiger, als man zunächst meinen könnte, obwohl beide Faktoren zunächst als Antagonisten erscheinen: ...

Now you clearly see the subordinate clause introduced by *obwohl*.

There are several types of "uneingeleitete Nebensätze". The above is called "Uneingeleiteter Konzessivsatz" or ["Uneingeleiteter Einräumungssatz"](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Komplex/Form/uneingeleitet.html#Anchor-Uneingeleiteter-47857).

Comment: Just to make sure... are you saying that the full stop there is a misstake? I fully agree with your answer but the text does not have a comma there...

Comment: @Emanuel: Yes, that's right, there should be a comma. This is what user unknown had already noted.

Comment: Great answer, since I failed to make sense of comments.

Comment: An interesting consequence of the existence of uneingeleitete Nebensätze and the subject–verb inversion in main clauses after subordinate clauses is that constructs of the form "verb noun, verb noun" are grammatically correct without distinguishing in any way between main and subordinate clause ("Haste Scheiße am Fuß, haste Scheiße am Fuß" – Andreas Brehme).

Comment: @Philipp: Nice example! (And _that's_ an "Uneingeleiteter Konditionalsatz" `:-)`) At least one can still tell what the main clause is.

Comment: A concessive clause would have *auch* in the subordinate clause (and optionally *doch* or similar in the main clause). In the given example, the subordinate clause has *doch*, which makes the meaning causal.