# Verb has occupied the first position of sentence

Tags: meaning, word-order

The below sentence is at the ending of 3rd paragraph [here](https://www.allgemeine-allgemeine.com/politik/gruene-heissen-ab-sofort-grueninnen/)

> Alle möglichen und unmöglichen geschlechtsspezifischen Diskriminierungen sollen aus Sprache und Leben der Grünen verbannt werden. Glimmt da nicht vielleicht sogar ein winzig kleiner Hoffnungsschimmer für alle Männer mit? **Galt doch die Bezeichnung “Depp” bislang ausschließlich ihnen.**

I am having hard time to understand that the verb Galt has occupied the first position of sentence.

I know we can use verb at first position when the sentence is in question, imperativ form or in conditional sentence where "Wenn" is omitted 
however in above sentence these possibilities doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: See also https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9533/verberstsatz-mit-doch and https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4533/sentence-starting-with-a-verb-without-question-or-conditional.

Answer (score 3):

This is an ellipsis, i.e. an incomplete sentence. The full sentence would be:

> *Glimmt da nicht vielleicht sogar ein winzig kleiner Hoffnungsschimmer für alle Männer mit?*
>   **Denn es** galt doch die Bezeichnung “Depp” bislang ausschließlich ihnen.

*Denn* is a conjunction. It is used to join this sentence to the preceding sentence which is a question. This conjunction does not count as part of the main clause. It starts at *"es"*.

*Es* is an expletive pronoun. If present, it plays the role of a subject in this sentence. It occupies the first position of this main clause (because the conjugation *"denn"* ist not really part of the main clause), and so the verb *"galt"* happily stands where it belongs to.

Comment: Daß es sich um eine Ellipse handelt, halte ich für zweifelhaft. Sätze wie *Ist es doch eine Tatsache, daß* können nicht auf *Denn es ist es eine Tatsache, daß* zurückgeführt werden.

Comment: @DavidVogt: 1. *»Dass«* schreibt man schon seit 22 Jahren nicht mehr mit *»ß«*! 2. Ich gebe dir völlig recht. Ich habe ja auch nirgendwo etwas derartiges behauptet.

Comment: Verstehe ich nicht. Willst du sagen, daß es sich bei dem Satz des Fragenden um eine Ellipse handelt, bei meinem Beispiel aber nicht? Aber wieso sollten denn zwei parallele Sätze unterschiedlich hergeleitet werden? Ein Beispiel mit *gelten*: *Derweil legt im Inneren ein Schreiner letzte Hand an. Gilt es doch, nebst Brandschutz- auch Hygienevorschriften gerecht zu werden.* Hier kann nicht *denn es* weggelassen sein, da man sonst zwei *es* hätte.

Comment: Ich will damit sagen: 1. »daß« ist schon seit 22 Jahren falsch!. 2. Im Beispiel des Fragestellers kommt kein expletives *»es«* vor. Das füge ich erst in der Vervollständigung der Ellipse ein. In deinem Beispiel ist das *»es«* aber schon vorhanden, und durch die falsche "Vervollständigung" entsteht ein Satz, in dem zweimal das expletive *»es«* vorkommt. Und das ist falsch, und somit hast du damit recht, dass dein Beispiel **nicht** auf diese Art auf einen anderen Satz zurückgeführt werden kann, während ich aber auch niemals behauptet habe, dass das mit deinem Beispiel funktionieren würde.

Comment: Nichts gegen "daß". Die Rechtschreibkorrektur hat zwar eine harte Zeit damit, aber z.B. auf Twitter spart es 25% der Buchstaben im Wort. Außerdem: was 1997 richtig war, kann 2019 nicht falsch sein, es sei denn, man ordnet sich einer Willkürherrschaft unter, die festlegt, was richtig und falsch ist.

Answer (score 2):

## Uses of V1 sentences

In German, independent V1 sentences (i.e. sentences with the finite verb in first position) are used to form yes-no questions.

> **Hast** du meine Brille gesehen? – Nö.
> Have you seen my glasses? – Nope.

Subordinate V1 clauses function as conditional clauses.

> **Hat** der Minister gelogen, muß er zurücktreten.
> **Wenn** der Minister gelogen hat, muß er zurücktreten.
> If the minister lied, he has to resign.

Some people claim that the conditional use is derived from the yes-no question.

> Hat der Minister gelogen? Dann muß er zurücktreten.

This claim matches with the fact that conditional V1 clauses cannot be postponed.

> *Der Minister muß zurücktreten, hat er gelogen.
> Der Minister muß zurücktreten, **wenn** er gelogen hat.

## Construction in question

Let's look at some examples.

> Sicherlich gebührt der Defensive großes Lob, **war** es **doch** bereits das dritte Spiel ohne Gegentreffer.
> Surely the defense deserves credit, because it was the third game already without conceding a goal.
>
> Früh fanden aber alle ins Bett, **war** es **doch** ein anstrengender Tag.
> But everyone was off to bed early, because it had been a trying day.
>
> Sein Rücktritt war abzusehen, **hatte** er **doch** das Parlament belogen.
> His resignation was to be expected, because he had lied to parliament.

As the translation indicates, postponed V1 clauses are interpreted as causal.
Note that the V1 clauses need to contain *doch*. This makes them different from sentences with causal conjunctions, where *doch* is omitted. Duden actually has a separate entry for this type of *doch* (Bedeutung 2: [Link](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/doch_Adverb#Bedeutung2)).

> Sicherlich gebührt der Defensive großes Lob, **weil** es bereits das dritte Spiel ohne Gegentreffer war.
> Sein Rücktritt war abzusehen, **denn** er hatte das Parlament belogen.

Causal V1 clauses belong to written language. They hardly, if ever, occur in spoken language.

## Sentence in question

The sentence in question has one additional complication.

> Alle möglichen und unmöglichen geschlechtsspezifischen Diskriminierungen sollen aus Sprache und Leben der Grünen verbannt werden. Glimmt da nicht vielleicht sogar ein winzig kleiner Hoffnungsschimmer für alle Männer mit? **Galt doch die Bezeichnung “Depp” bislang ausschließlich ihnen.**

This is *metacommunicative causality*. Compare:

> Die Frau lügt, weil die doch total nervös ist!
> That woman is lying. She is so nervous!

The *weil*-sentence can be interpreted as giving a reason why the speaker claims the woman to be lying (as opposed to giving a reason why the woman is lying).

And this is exactly how the V1 sentence in question is interpreted: As giving a reason for why the writer believes that gender-neutral language carries "a glimmer of hope". Note that the writer is being ironic, though.

Comment: See for instance https://homepage.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/Karin.Pittner/dochV1.pdf.

Answer (score 0):

This is a conditional sentence. The two sentences below are the same

> Galt doch die Bezeichnung „Depp“ bislang ausschließlich ihnen.
>
> Wo doch die Bezeichnung „Depp“ bislang ausschließlich ihnen galt.

This *wo* refers to a situation when the condition was met.

Comment: The second sentence is a conditional sentence, but the first one is not. And the question is dealing with the first sentence which is different from the second. You post does not answer the question.